# Create and write and read registry in C#

Tags: c#, registry, clickonce

During my installation (I'm using Clickonce) I'd like to create registry my project is with .Net 3.5 currently.

My application is 32 bits and it can be installed in a 32 or 64 bits machine, I have some issue while creating the registry.

In the function VerifyReg I create the registry if they didn't exist (My program is the name of the parent branch that should be under Software depending in 32 or 64 bits machine.

My problem is in the function : CreateMoreRegistryKeys in

```
RegistryKey RegKeyWow64 = RegKeyMain.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node", true);
```

I have an error writing into the registry even if I'm an Administrator of the machine

This is the function did I miss something during the creation and the reading ?

```
public void VerifyReg()
 {
    string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Myprogram";
    RegistryKey RegKeyMain = Registry.LocalMachine;
    RegistryKey skSub = null;

    skSub = RegKeyMain.OpenSubKey(keyName);
    if (skSub == null)
    {
         skSub = RegKeyMain.CreateSubKey(keyName);
    }
    CreateMoreRegistryKeys();
}
public void CreateMoreRegistryKeys()
{
    bool bIs64bits = Environment.Is64BitOperatingSystem;

    string keyName = @"SOFTWARE\Myprogram\Folder";
    RegistryKey RegKeyMain = Registry.LocalMachine;

    if (bIs64bits)
    {
      keyName = @"Myprogram\Folder";
      RegistryKey RegKeyWow64 = RegKeyMain.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node", true);
      CreateRegKeyFor64or32Bits(RegKeyWow64, keyName);
    }
    else
    {
       CreateRegKeyFor64or32Bits(RegKeyMain, keyName);
    }
}

public void CreateRegKeyFor64or32Bits(RegistryKey RegKeyMain, string keyName)
{
        RegistryKey skSubWy = RegKeyMain.CreateSubKey(keyName, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree);
        if (skSubWy != null)
        {
            ..Do something
        }
    }
```

Comment: for what its worth .... I am running as a Admin on a 64 bit machine and had no problem creating the key. I didn't change any code.

Comment: ClickOnce applications run with lowered privileges (per design), so even though you're logged in as admin, you don't have admin rights.

Comment: @MicahArmantrout : if I understand you try my code and it's working on your side ? in the same code I have a function to validate if I'm admin or not and it's gave me different value (first run = true, second = false) `private static bool IAmAdmin()
        { 
            bool isElevated;
            WindowsIdentity windowsIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
            WindowsPrincipal windowsPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(windowsIdentity);
             isElevated =  windowsPrincipal.IsInRole(WindowsBuiltInRole.Administrator);


            return isElevated;
        }`

Comment: @PawBaltzersen: is that mean that a standard user cannot install ? and the registry cannot be created ?

Comment: Yes I ran the code in a console app so being in a click once app could be key

Comment: I just ran it in a click once console app and had no trouble

Comment: @MicahArmantrout ok thank I'm wondering in this case why I have the message : Clickonce registry access violation

Comment: I am running as admin ... are you ?

Comment: Yes and the UAC is on the second level, and as I said the function : IAmAdmin return the first time that Iam a admin and the second not !!!!

Comment: The message is : ClickOnce Deployement Error Details : Requested registry access is not allowed, this error message I have it on : `RegistryKey RegKeyWow64 = RegKeyMain.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node", true);` I have Win 7 64 bits